PowerShell, Get-CimInstance -QueryDialect CQL
is CQL (CIM Query Language) really available on Windows or is the CQL option of the -QueryDialect parameter just a once meant to be implemented but never was option? whatever I use as a -Query, I get a NotImplemented CimException when I use -QueryDialect CQL
> Get-CimInstance -Query "SELECT * FROM CIM_LogicalDisk" -QueryDialect WQL

DeviceID DriveType ProviderName VolumeName Size          FreeSpace
-------- --------- ------------ ---------- ----          ---------
C:       3                                 267839860736  85690933248
D:       3                      Data       3298398564352 913563791360


> Get-CimInstance -Query "SELECT * FROM CIM_LogicalDisk" -QueryDialect CQL

Get-CimInstance : Invalid query type
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-CimInstance -Query "SELECT * FROM CIM_LogicalDisk" -QueryDialect  ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotImplemented: (:) [Get-CimInstance], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x80041018,Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimCmdlets.GetCimInstanceCommand


I think it's for "Cassandra databases"?  https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/dse/overview/cql-about.html
